# Change the legend enteries by column values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend

I'm struggling a lot with changing the labels in the legend in matplotlib charts.
This is my graph:
[image]

I would like to change the legend so the labels will be based on the values in column called "name",from the column name.

This is how I created the original graph:

```
ax = plt.figure()
df.iloc[3000:3005,:].loc[:,float_cols].T.plot(figsize=(10,6))
plt.title('title',size=(20))
plt.ylabel('Y', size=(14))
plt.xlabel('x', size=(14))
```

This is how I have tried to change the legend to the column name:

```
targets = df['name']

ax = plt.figure()
df.iloc[3000:3005,:].loc[:,float_cols].T.plot(figsize=(10,6).label=targets)
plt.title('title',size=(20))
plt.ylabel('Y', size=(14))
plt.xlabel('x', size=(14))
```

but it didn't work. I have also tried other ways, like using plt.legend, but it didn't work.

**My end goal: To change the legend to have labels based on the names of those observations (from column name)**

Edit: I have tried:

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  plt.plot(df, df.iloc[3000:3005,:].loc[:,float_cols], label = df.columns['name'])

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but it didn't work got this error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

also tried this:

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  plt.plot(df, df.iloc[3000:3005,:].loc[:,float_cols], label = df.columns[i])

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But also got error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
>   (8606, 444) and (5, 438)

EDIT 2: Tried this:

```
targets = df['name']

plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[3000:3005,:], label = targets[i])

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

got the error:

> in 
>         3 plt.figure()
>         4 for i in range(df.shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls7tZ.png)):
>   ----> 5     plt.plot(df.iloc[3000:3005,:], label = targets[i])
>         6 
>         7 plt.legend()
>
> ~.conda\envs\reut\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)
>       869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
>       870         try:
>   --> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>       872 
>       873             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> ~.conda\envs\reut\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_value(self, series, key)    4403         k =
>   self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")    4404         try:
>   -> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))    4406         except KeyError
>   as e1:    4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer()
>   or self.is_boolean()):
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 0

Comment: You can loop over the columns using regular matplolib `plt.plot()`, adapting this example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-legend-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using matplotlib regular `plt.plot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

targets = ['cos(x)', 'sin(x)', 'cos(x) + sin(x)']
d = {'col1': np.cos(x), 'col2': np.sin(x), 'col3': np.sin(x) + np.cos(x)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

plt.figure()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  plt.plot(x, df.iloc[:,i], label = targets[i])

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can change `targets` to what ever you want, including `df['name']`, depending on the organization of your dataframe.

Finally, if you don't have an `x` vector, just use `plt.plot( df.iloc[:,i], label = targets[i])` instead, and it will plot your data with respect to position indices, as in your example in your question.

EDIT based on comments and discussion in chat:

For your case, you can try something similar to:

```
indexes_wanted = [2000, 100, 3200]
targets = df['names']

plt.figure()
for i in indexes_wanted:
  plt.plot(x, df.iloc[i, :][float_cols], label = targets.iloc[i])

plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: it didn't work, youcan see in my original post. I don't know why it doesn't work , maybe because it's not x-y but it has more dimension,, so the label is not the name of the column, but value from the column

Comment: right now the legend labels are the index and I would like to take the values from column "name"

Comment: You might want to edit your initial post then, as  "from column name" is misleading.

Comment: I have edited now, I hope it is more clear, if you have any idea I would love to know

Comment: it didn't work, I got KeyError: 0 , I have added to my original post how I did it, naybe I didn't do it as you meant

Comment: Could you please give the shapes of `df.iloc[3000:3005,:]`, and `targets` in what you did ?

Comment: df.iloc[3000:3005,:] shape-> (5, 438) , targets.shape-> (8606,)

Comment: Where are the 5 names corresponding to your 5 curves, knowing that `targets = df['name']` is `(8606,)` instead of `(5,)` ?

Comment: the thing is that I don't know which names are match for 3000:3005, I want the cocde to be able to tell me, 3000:3005 is just a random observations I chose

Comment: Well if you don;t know how your dataframe is organized no one will be able to tell you.

Do you mean that in df you also have 8606 curves of length 438 each, and here for the example you took the 5 ones between 3000 and 30005 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209433/discussion-between-reut-and-liris).

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if  the solution is now satisfying.